# I would like to highlight a rectangle in ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular

I have created an OCR application, when a pdf file is processed I get a bounding box which shows the coordinates for a text within a pdf file I would like to use it and highlight it in my pdf-viewer. I'm using ng2-pdf-viewer.

```
<pdf-viewer *ngIf='extension=="pdf" || extension == "PDF"' [src]="selectedPDF[index]"
          [original-size]="true" [fit-to-page]="true" class="pdf-viewer-class">
</pdf-viewer>
```

I have tried 2-3 ways but they are not working and I'm unable to find a solution online.

Comment: for that you need to use JavaScript For Eg : [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_rect.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In html:

```
<canvas #myCanvas width="860px" height="1106px" style="z-index: 20;position: absolute;left: 0;"></canvas>
          <pdf-viewer id="pdfViewerID" *ngIf='extension=="pdf" || extension == "PDF"' [src]="selectedPDF[index]"
            (after-load-complete)="afterLoadComplete($event)" [show-all]="false" [(page)]='pageNumber'
            [original-size]="true" [fit-to-page]="true" class="pdf-viewer-class"
            [render-text]="true" [render-text-mode]="2">
          </pdf-viewer>
```

In Ts:

```
 @ViewChild('myCanvas') myCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
    
      public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    this.context = this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    this.context.beginPath();
            var editedboundingBox = this.getOuterRectanglePoints(boundingBox);
            this.context.moveTo(editedboundingBox[0],editedboundingBox[1]);
            this.context.lineTo(editedboundingBox[2],editedboundingBox[3]);
            this.context.lineTo(editedboundingBox[4],editedboundingBox[5]);
            this.context.lineTo(editedboundingBox[6],editedboundingBox[7]);
            this.context.lineTo(editedboundingBox[0],editedboundingBox[1]);
            this.context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 153, 171, 0.3)';
            this.context.fill();
            this.context.strokeStyle = 'darkred';
            this.context.lineWidth = 2;
            this.context.stroke();
            this.context.closePath();
```

Comment: Hi  user9537859, may I know what to write in method this.getOuterRectanglePoints(boundingBox)