# How can I draw or insert a shape into a PDF in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project that lets the user sign a pdf using React. Right now I'm displaying the pdf on an Iframe component and would like to let the user place a rectangle on the pdf that shows where would he want the sign to be displayed.

Is there any way for me to let the user "draw" that rectangle in the displayed pdf?

Right now my component looks like this:

```
import { PDFDocument } from "pdf-lib";
// import useffect
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const PDFRenderer = (props) => {
const { data } = props;
const [docurl, pdfBytes] = data;
const [sizes, setSizes] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  async function getSizes() {
  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);
  const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
  const page = pages[0];
  const { width, height } = page.getSize();
  setSizes([width, height]);
}
  getSizes();
}, [pdfBytes]);
return (
  <div className="renderer">
    {sizes && (
      <iframe
        src={docurl + "#zoom=100"}
        width={sizes[0] * 1.5}
        height={sizes[1]}
      />
    )}
  </div>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a problem ask them to add the comments in their PDF, then send a copy of the printed pdf. Since the Iframe and its contents belong to the client, only they can tell you if the PDF was displayed in the IFrame or downloaded into an external application.

Thus you have no means other than politely request they upload a reproduction for you to copy the relative page location. If you want better control, perhaps you need an application/pdf such as Adobe produce.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to me that Luis Rada, asked for advice on how to do something in React and not advise on the process ...

anyway, more people solved a similar problem, just not in react:
[Re-render a page at any time](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/605)

[I would like to highlight a rectangle in ng2-pdf-viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887027/i-would-like-to-highlight-a-rectangle-in-ng2-pdf-viewer)

For React i found just [pdf creator - with rectangle](https://react-pdf.org/repl?example=rect)
And similar [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590845/draw-rectangle-in-canvas-with-loaded-pdf-file-using-pdf-js)